# Display all the tables which are having zero records in a particular schema in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to display all the tables which are having zero records count in abc schema in snowflake :

I used this query from web, :

```
select t.table_schema || '.' ||  t.table_name as "table_name"
from information_schema.tables t
where t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
and t.row_count = 0
order by "table_name";
```

and it gave me the results, but I am not able to understand the first 3 lines of the query.

can anyone help!

Also, I want to get the table size, for which I used below query, but getting zero records :

```
SELECT table_catalog, 
   table_name, 
   active_bytes / 1024 AS storage_usage_MB 
FROM   "INFORMATION_SCHEMA".table_storage_metrics 
where TABLE_CATALOG in ('TEST_DB');
```

Comment: If you want us to help explain the first 3 lines you get with your information_schema.tables query you should add the 3 lines result here.

Comment: The first three lines are `SELECT`/`FROM`/`WHERE` clauses which are very basic SQL.  What needs to be explained?  The `||` is the Standard SQL operator for string concatenation.

Comment: As for second question. In the documentation it clearly says `To query this view, you must use the ACCOUNTADMIN role. The view is visible to other views and can be queried, but the queries will return no rows.`. Are you using the ACCOUNTADMIN role? And can't you just use the column `information_schema.tables.BYTES` for that? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/table_storage_metrics.html

Comment: There is even an example for that: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/tables.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was aware of basic sql clauses , but not of concatenation operator, Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time, I got the answer by reading snowflake official documentation:

```
use schema your_database.information_schema;

select * from tables where table_schema = 'your_schema' and  ROW_COUNT=0 ;
```

Using above query, you will get all the tables with zero records.

@CMe  , Thanks for your time, Here is the result for first three lines :

```
select t.table_schema || '.' ||  t.table_name as "table_name"
from information_schema.tables t
where t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
```

-------Output----------

```
|  Row    |  table_name               |
--------------------------------------
|  1      |  schema_name.Table_Name_1 |
|  2     |  schema_name.Table_Name_2 |
.
.
. so on
```